# Is the batsman lbw or bowled in this scenario?

Tags: cricket

If the ball hits the batsman's pads in front of the wicket but then the ball goes on to hit the stumps, does the bowler still have the option of appealing for an lbw or will the batsman be given out bowled regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bowled. Refer to [Law 32.2](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/bowled):

> The striker is out Bowled if his/her wicket is fairly broken as in 32.1, even though a decision against him/her for any other method of dismissal would be justified.

Also note that the fielding team *never* has to appeal for a specific method of dismissal; [Law 31.4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/appeals):

> An appeal “How’s That?” covers all ways of being out.